# Image in UIAlertView not showing (iPhone dev.)

Tags: ios, image, uialertview, addsubview

I had an image showing in my alert view just fine. But when I chose to make a tab bar based application and used the exact same code as before, the picture just did not appear, any idea why this might be?

Here is my code that worked just fine in the single view based application:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"AlertView"
                              message:@"\n"
                              @"\n"
                              @"\n"
                              @"\n"
                              @"\n"
                              @"Created by: \n"
                              @"Just testing \n"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"QWER Ahri.jpg"]];//add Icon.png
        logo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        logo.frame = CGRectMake(90, 40, 100, 120);
        [alert addSubview:logo];
        [alert show];
```

I also tried this method, which indeed worked fine in the single view based application, just like the previous one, but not in the tab bar based one,

```
 UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ahri is good with" message:@"Vayne, Ezreal, Caitlyn, Katarina, Alistar, Leona, Miss Fortune, Taric" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-15, -147, 314, 85)];

        NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QWER Ahri.jpg"]];
        UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [imageView setImage:bkgImg];


        [successAlert addSubview:imageView];

        [successAlert show];
```

Any help would be highly appreciated  :)

Comment: Strongly reconsider adding your own views directly to views you don't directly control. For all you know, the show method goes through all views and removes all other views than its own.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude or anything, but that did not really help at all.

Comment: You're trying to do something that while it may work now, you can't guarantee will work in iOS 7 or iOS 8 or iOS 8.1 (putting your views inside a view hierarchy that someone else has control over). The answer is to not do that. I don't have a specific answer handy saying which UIAlertView alternative (made especially so that you can put your own stuff in) to pick because I haven't really used any of them, but I know that they're out there.

Comment: ok, I guess I'll try to come up with an alternative way of doing it, thanks though.